# Trigger to not delete Data from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

I have a table called PaperInfo and sample data on the table is:

```
PaperID   Type   Description
1         T      Level 1
2         S      Level 2
3         V      Level 3
```

How can enforce a trigger where no one can delete a record from the above table. When some one tries to delete it for example as below:

```
Delete from dbo.paperInfo 
WHERE PaperID = 1
```

It should display an error message saying "Cannot Delete Records from Paperinfo Table"

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. This will replace the delete operation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER td_PaperInfo 
    ON  PaperInfo 
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Cannot Delete Records from Paperinfo Table', 16, 1)
END
```

Comment: Small Correction it is RAISERROR

Comment: Really sorry buddy. I actually pasted the code after testing it. No idea how that `A` got lost in the process! ;)